# Generic function in Golang to match variable and type passed

Tags: go

I want to write a function which takes two arguments `interface{}` and a type and return `true` if the interface is of the type passed, else return `false`.

I am a beginner in reflection and main challenge I see is how to take type as a function parameter.

For example:

```
func checkType(val interface{}, t <??>){
   if reflect.Typeof(val) == t {
      return true
   }else{
      return false
   }
}

checkType("hello",<int type>) // returns false
checkType("hello",<string type>) // returns true
```

I am not able to fill the code in all the `<>` portions to achieve the required behavior.

Edit: Got queries about the safe type cast operator and also intent of my question. Though the methods suggested would help to achieve the type cast, the question was mainly to enhance the academic knowledge about Go reflection.

Comment: You may use `reflect.Type` as the type of the 2nd parameter. Does that suit you? But then you have to call it like: `checkType("hello", reflect.TypeOf(0))` for `int`. All in all, I don't see the benefit if this function.

Comment: Can you also explain what you need this for? The reason I'm asking is the need to to what you're after is a clear "code smell" in Go: you might be trying to solve a problem in a wrong way, and we may be currently experiencing a case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @icza, I thought about this, but felt there should be a more elegant way than to declare unwanted literals in code.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a function like this, it's already a built-in feature of the language:

```
i := "hello"

_, ok := i.(int)    // ok is false
_, ok := i.(string) // ok is true
```

Comment: You can't do `t := int; _, ok := i.(t)`, and that's what the OP was basically asking for.

Comment: The OP's example doesn't show that. It shows calling `checkType()` with a type literal.

Comment: Okay, you beat me to this, but by extension, to _demonstrate_ what you're after you will inevitably have a call with some literal at the top level of your call chain ;-)

Comment: It really depends on the goal. If the OP has a broader goal, not mentioned in the question, you may well be right.